# How to define a Spring bean using annotation instead of XML?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have defined in a xml config file:

```
<bean id="bootstrap" class="com.package.Bootstrap"></bean>
```

this works fine.

The bootsrap class :

```
public class Bootstrap {

   @PostConstruct
   public void onServerStart() {
      System.out.println("PRINTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS");
   }
}
```

The method gets fired.

But how can I get rid of the xml part, and annotate bootstrap to be a bean instead?

I have

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
```

and

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.package" />
```

But I **was wondering what the annotation** used should be that replaces:

```
<bean id="bootstrap" class="com.package.Bootstrap"></bean>
```

I could not find anything about this online and in the spring docs :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's documentation regarding this; you'll want a stereotype annotation like `@Component`.

[Stereotype bean annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations)

Comment: `@Component` ties you to Spring.  Consider using JSR-330 annotations (`@Named`, `@Inject`)instead: http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-and-jsr-330-inject-and-named-example/

Comment: @JJZabkar So does `<mvc:annotation-driven />`, they're already tied to Spring.

Comment: Yes, but in separate files though.  Suppose you annotate your beans with @Component/@Service/etc.  That would mean all your classes have `import` (compile-time) dependencies on the Spring Framework.  You'll still have your XML configuration.  (Continued)

Comment: Now consider a scenario where you need to re-factor--say you need to get rid of Spring (i.e., replace it with GWT or some other DI provider).  If you had used `@Inject`/`@Named`--Java standard annotations--you could have been more loosely coupled.  It's akin to using JPA annotations instead of Hibernate annotations--don't tie yourself to an implementation (Read: Spring Framework) where you don't have to.

Comment: @JJZabkar From a purely technical standpoint, this is obvious--I don't think explaining platform migration is necessary. From a realistic standpoint, meh.

Comment: @JJZabkar - I'm with you on this one. Whenever you can write code that doesn't tie you into a particular framework - do it!

Answer (score 4):

this is a simple example that I have just made:

**Main.java**

```
package the.test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AbstractApplicationContext aac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Person.class, Phones.class);
    Person person = aac.getBean(Person.class);
    System.out.println(person.getPhones().getPhoneOne());
    System.out.println(person.getPhones().getPhoneTwo());
    System.out.println(person.getSurname());
    System.out.println(person.getName());
    System.out.println(person.getAge());
    aac.close();

    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
package the.test;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration

//you may use @ComponentScan("the.test") here and omit declaring 
//"Phone.class" in the main method 

public class Person {
private int age;
private String name;
private String surname;

private Phones phones;

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
@Value("33")
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Value("John")
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

@Value("Due")
public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public Phones getPhones() {
    return phones;
}
@Resource
public void setPhones(Phones phones) {
    this.phones = phones;
}
}
```

**Phones.java**

```
package the.test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Phones {
private String PhoneOne;
private String PhoneTwo;

public String getPhoneOne() {
    return PhoneOne;
}

@Value("987654321")
public void setPhoneOne(String phoneOne) {
    PhoneOne = phoneOne;
}

public String getPhoneTwo() {
    return PhoneTwo;
}

@Value("123456")
public void setPhoneTwo(String phoneTwo) {
    PhoneTwo = phoneTwo;
}

}
```

this is completely based on Spring Annotation and is made on spring framework 4.2.5

hope it helps.