# @scope("prototype") not working properly

Tags: spring

Consider the following configuration

```
 public class MainApp {
        public static void main(String args[]){

            ApplicationContext ac=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("src/Beans.xml");
            HelloWorld obj1=(HelloWorld) ac.getBean("helloWorld");
            obj1.setMessage("OBJ1");
            HelloWorld obj2=(HelloWorld) ac.getBean("helloWorld");
            //obj2.setMessage("OBJ2");
            System.out.println(obj1.getMessage());
            System.out.println(obj2.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Scope("prototype")

    public class HelloWorld {
    String message;
        public String getMessage() {
            return "Your Message:"+message;
        }
        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
        }


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
               <context:annotation-config />
               <context:component-scan base-package="SpringDemo.src"  />
                 <bean id="helloWorld" class="src.HelloWorld">
           </bean>
          </beans>
```

If i am not wrong it is showing the behavior of a Singleton scope. can someone let me know why it is not behaving as a "Prototype" scope?

Comment: class name `src.HelloWorld` is wrong. You do not need to specify `src` directory as a `package`

Comment: If i remove it, it shows an error Cannot find class [HelloWorld] for bean with name 'helloWorld' defined in class path resource [src/Beans.xml];   I am getting the output, but its for singleton scope and not for prototype

Comment: @Aashish what exactly is the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: Its printing                                                        Your Message:OBJ1
Your Message:OBJ1     while it should print  Your Message:OBJ1
Your Message:null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this  `<bean id="helloWorld" class="src.HelloWorld">` in the xml configuration. When no scope is specified the `scope` defaults to `singleton`. The xml configuration overrides the annotation. Remove  `@Scope("prototype")` and add `scope="prototype"` in the xml.

Comment: But Evgeny, I want to define the scope using annotations

Comment: Then use only annotations and remove the xml bean definition

Comment: If i am removing it, i am getting an error Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'helloWorld' is defined

Comment: I'm not very familiar with annotation declaration, but I think you need @Component along with @Scope("prototype")

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126537/how-to-define-a-spring-bean-using-annotation-instead-of-xml and this http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations

Comment: I have tried adding that @Evgeny, didnt work. Thanks for the help

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="SpringDemo.src"  /> this looks wrong to me. the value should be the package of the class

Comment: That was it. Thanks. But we are not defining the bean in application contxt.xml then how it is identifying the "helloWorld" in ac.getBean("helloWorld")..my understanding is that it is because of the @component annotation

Comment: Yes. <context:component-scan base-package="your class package"  /> tells Spring to scan these packages for annotated classes.

Comment: It's a good practice to keep the packages to scan as narrow as posible(only the package with the annotated classes). Too many classes to scan will cause the app to start slowly

Comment: Just to add on, how it is retrieving the name "helloWorld" for the bean. We are no where mentioning this name

Comment: Not sure about it but I think it's the default. 'public class HelloWorld {' default bean id is helloWorld. You can override it with the annotation value.

Comment: I'd upvote this answer 10x if I could. I was banging my head against the computer for 3 days, and the problem was simply some forgotten configuration on a xml file.